# Spawn grunt task from ruby and terminate it again

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to start a grunt task from ruby. This task runs forever, because it starts up a server.

Later in the ruby script I want to shutdown that server I started with grunt.

I have the following now:

```
grunt_proxy_pid = spawn("TARGET_PORT=#{port+1} PROXY_PORT=#{port} grunt server:test", :out=>"/dev/null")
Process.detach grunt_proxy_pid

... ruby code ...

Process.kill "SIGINT", grunt_proxy_pid
```

However this does not terminate the grunt task, only the shell command that executed the `grunt server:test` command (In the task manager the task with the pid 'grunt_proxy_pid' is something like `sh -c TARGET_PORT=3523 PROXY_PORT=3224 grunt server:test` However the grunt process itself has another pid.

How can I get the grunt tasks pid so that I can terminate the grunt task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turned out that setting the environment variables this way was the problem. setting them this way works:

```
grunt_proxy_pid = spawn({
  "TARGET_PORT" => "#{port+1}",
  "PROXY_PORT" => "#{port}"
}, "grunt server:test", :out=>"/dev/null")
Process.detach grunt_proxy_pid
```

This way the grunt command is NOT started with `sh -c` and `grunt_proxy_pid` is the pid of the grunt process itself.